# Should this question be cross-posted to Islam.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, migration

[What is the explanation for the basis of Buddhislamic faith in Dune Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-is-the-explanation-for-the-basis-of-buddhislamic-faith-in-dune-universe)

Part of the question is clearly in-universe SciFi.

But part is also out-of-universe theological.

Should this question be cross-posted to Islam.SE (with suitable tweaks to make it clearly on-topic)?

Existing answers weren't very satisfactory theologically-based (the only one that was extensively out of universe based - by Darius - was clearly wrong in major points)

Comment: I don't think the scope of "how might islam and buddhism be reconciled" would be right for [Islam.SE], but I've notified the mods there and asked if they would like to add their input.

Comment: Cross-posting, in general, is not generally recommended. However, if there are specific aspects that aren't addressed, but which would be more relevant to a different SE site, a new question focusing specifically on those aspects posted on the other site might be appropriate. Given that you seem interested in what commonalities might exist between Buddhist and Islamic beliefs, perhaps asking about philosophical commonalities on philosophy.se might provide some decent information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental question of "Can Islam and Buddhism be reconciled" might be on-topic for Islam.SE, but it's far too broad of scope to be well-received on the site.  There are many flavours of Islam, just as there are many flavours of Buddhism (heck, there's many flavours of Buddislam, for that matter), so without at least limiting the scope to *particular* interpretations of both, or to *particular* (apparent) contradictions, answers would be either too numerous or too vague to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for throwing your hat in goldPseduo. I agree here.

Answer (score 7):

I do not see how the question can be edited to properly fit Islam.SE, at least without changing the question entirely.  As the core of the question currently stands, it would not be welcomed on Islam.SE, hence I believe it shouldn't be cross posted.

Answer (score -1):

In addition, deliberately cross posting questions is highly discouraged. If [it happens accidentally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195916/155668), it's usually accepted, but [purposely cross-posting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180389/155668) is not recommended.

Comment: Actually, you're not entirely correct. As per [Gilles' citing Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87739/clarification-regarding-cross-posting-rules): "Also from Jeff (comment on another answer): “[cross-posting] can be OK [in rare cases], so long as the question is tailored to each audience on the different sites and is materially different in each case. Just to be 100% clear, copy-pasting a question across sites with no changes is considered abusive behavor.”  What I had in mind was explicitly the "question is tailored to each audience" scenario.

Comment: [Some sites](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/667/864) are actually perfectly fine with deliberate cross-posting, so long as certain rules of ettiquette are followed.